# angularjs conceptional frontend workflow implementation (beginner)

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm not very experienced with frontend development in general and just started with angularjs.

what is the best practice for implementing a worklow
where the user is answering questions with input 
fields and checkboxes in every step with angularjs?

In the middle there is a div that is constantly 
changing in every step with different html elements.

The right displays information about what has been selected so far so the html elements don't change.

what would be the best practice to implement this scenario?
I thought about creating all of these divs and then swapping them out 
with ngSwitch based on the step the user is in.

Comment: this is more a topic for UX, http://ux.stackexchange.com/ do an abstraction, get some advice there and when you try to do your implememtation get back to SO.

Comment: While your concept would probably work, I believe it would lead to chaos. I would shoot for routing the user through the app in order to  gain a nice UX & scalable architecture. This can be done neatly via the built in router or `ui-router`. ALso I agree with @jack.the.ripper

Comment: You create directive, which uses the input json data to create the Answer fields (input/checkbox) based on your model. When you click next, update the model and you get a new Answer form

Answer (score 0):

I hope following might be a good solution(tested by me)...

Firstly , your html should be binded with a data you want to display .
Then you bind a click function on your next button where a counter increases and you can fetch data at that index and re-initialize your binding to show the data.

And in the right you can bind a variable in ng-repeat(list or map) to show your information.